# Possible to return node name from BuildRowSetFromXML() function?

Tags: ampscript, xml, marketing-cloud

I'm attempting to loop through an XML block and return the node *names* in addition to the *values*.  Anyone know if that's possible?

```
%%[
  var @xml, @lineitems
  set @xml = "<order_items><item><sku>SKU1</sku></item><item><sku>SKU2</sku></item></order_items>"
  set @lineitems = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/order_items/item/*",0)

  set @rowCount = rowcount(@lineitems)

  for @i = 1 to @rowcount do
    set @lineitem = Row(@lineitems,@i)

    /* set @name = Field(@lineitem,"Name") */ /* this doesn't work */
    set @value = Field(@lineitem,"Value")
    outputline(concat("<br>name: ",@name, ", value: ",@value))

  next @i

]%%
```

Desired Output:

```
name: SKU, value: SKU1 
name: SKU, value: SKU2
```

The documentation on the [BuildRowSetFromXML()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromXML) function only includes `Name`, `XML` and `*_att` as retrievable columns in the result-set using the [Field()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/#Field) function, which probably means I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way I can think to accomplish this is to have your first row mimic your column header names and just call that each time you need the column name.  It is not exactly an elegant solution, but I do not believe there is one via AMPscript.